# How to add an attribute to an XML node in Java 1.4

Tags: java, xml

I tried:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(f);
Node mapNode = getMapNode(doc);
System.out.print("\r\n elementName "+ mapNode.getNodeName());//This works fine.

Element e = (Element) mapNode; //This is where the error occurs
//it seems to work on my machine, but not on the server.
e.setAttribute("objectId", "OBJ123");
```

But this throws a java.lang.ClassCastException error on the line that casts it to Element.  **mapNode is a valid node.**  I already have it printing out

I think maybe this code does not work in Java 1.4.  What I really need is an alternative to using Element.  I tried doing

```
NamedNodeMap atts = mapNode.getAttributes();
    Attr att = doc.createAttribute("objId");
    att.setValue(docId);    
    atts.setNamedItem(att);
```

But getAttributes() returns null on the server.  Even though its not and I am using the same document locally as on the server.  And it can print out the getNodeName() its just that the getAttributes() does not work.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is the exact stack trace?

Comment: The only useful info the stack trace says is java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: Throws it at the Element e = (Element) doc.getFirstChild() line

Comment: What does mapNode.getClass().getName() report?  If it's not an Element, knowing what it really is will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Being a valid node does not mean it is an element. What does 'getNodeName' print on both machines?

Comment: You should probably update your question title, but it does indicate your confusion. Node does not have a setAttribute method; Element does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a different dtd file on the server.  That was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Might the first child be a whitespace only text node or suchlike?

Try:

```
System.out.println(doc.getFirstChild().getClass().getName());
```

EDIT:

Just looked it up in my own code, you need:

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
```

Or:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("MyTag");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your cast of the output of doc.getFirstChild() is where you're getting your exception -- you're getting some non-Element Node object.  Does the line number on the stack trace point to that line?  You might need to do a doc.getChildNodes() and iterate to find the first Element child (doc root), skipping non-Element Nodes.

Your e.setAttribute() call looks sensible.  Assuming e is an Element and you actually get to that line...

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, the `ClassCastException` is probably not being thrown in `setAttribute`. Check the line number in the stack. My guess is that `getFirstChild()` is returning a `DocumentType`, not an `Element`.

Try this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(f);

Element e = (Element) doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild();
e.setAttribute("objectId", "OBJ123");
```

Update:

It seems like you are confusing `Node` and `Element`. `Element` is an implementation of `Node`, but certainly not the only one. So, not all `Node`'s are castable to `Element`. If the cast is working on one machine and not on another, it's because you're getting something else back from `getMapNode()` because the parsers are behaving differently. The XML parser is pluggable in Java 1.4, so you could be getting an entirely different implementation, from a different vendor, with different bugs even.

Since you're not posting `getMapNode()` we cannot see what it's doing, but you should be explicit about what node you want it to return (using `getElementsByTagName` or otherwise).

Comment: Totally agree with your update, if it is a different parser on the server it could be handling whitespace only text nodes differently, which would cause the error (depending on how getMapNode is written)